# How to copy tracks from Garmin GPSMAP 65 to Ubuntu Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, garmin

I have a Garmin GPSMAP 65 with a Micro SD card. The tracks recorded on the device don't seem to be on the SD card, which makes it seemingly impossible to copy them from the device using Linux.

Either of these 2 things could help me:

- Is there a way to save the tracks onto the SD card instead of the internal memory?
- Is there a setting that would allow ubuntu to recognize the Garmin GPSMAP 65 device as an SD card when connected via USB?

I have tried connecting via USB, but Ubuntu doesn't even show any new devices with e.g. `lsblk`

Comment: The [manual](https://www8.garmin.com/manuals/webhelp/GUID-EA40F185-39D1-4C3B-B512-7AA823FA3DB5/EN-US/GPSMAP_65_65s_OM_EN-US.pdf) says the SD is used for add'l storage or preloaded maps, and when connected to Win or MacOS both the device should show up as two separate drives/volumes. So it should show up in Linux as well - the prob may be that it doesn't auto-mount. Open terminal, give command `sudo dmesg -w`. Connect the Garmin to the USB. What does `dmesg` output show? Please don't answer in comment, rather edit the question to add the output.

Comment: @Peregrino69 Thanks for your helpful comment. Today I finally realized I should try a second cable, because even `dmesg` wasn't showing anything.

Comment: LOL :-D As USB cables are basically simple, dumb devices one would assume they're interchangeable, excepting of course that the ones strictly for charging don't do data transfer. I've bumped into this a few times myself with ebook readers (my Kindle was darn picky...), digital cameras and whatnot...

Answer (score 1):

After another hour spent today wondering, I finally realized to try another USB cable. I think all my issues were coming from a defective cable.

With the new cable and the Gpsmap 65 in `MTB` mode I get the following results with `sudo dmesg -w` which @peregrino69 suggested.

```
$ sudo dmesg -w | grep Garmin
[366555.328607] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: Garmin
[366564.028948] scsi 1:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Garmin   Garmin Flash     1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[366564.029569] scsi 1:0:0:1: Direct-Access     Garmin   Garmin SD Card   1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
```

The device now also shows up with

```
$ lsblk
NAME                  MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINTS
sdb                     8:16   1 14,6G  0 disk  /media/username/GARMIN
```

Now I can also copy the tracks from the device. They are in the `Garmin/GPX` directory. Here is the directory structure just for reference:

```
/media/username/GARMIN
├── Garmin
│   ├── BirdsEye
│   ├── CONNECT
│   ├── CustomMaps
│   ├── CustomSymbols
│   ├── Debugging
│   ├── EDM
│   ├── Express
│   ├── ExtData
│   ├── Filters
│   │   └── Geocache
│   ├── GPS
│   ├── GPX               <-- Here be tracks ;)
│   │   ├── Archive
│   │   └── Current
│   ├── Profiles
│   ├── SQL
│   │   └── temp
│   └── Text
└── System Volume Information
```